# How to add a tooltip to a customtkinter image (CTkImage)?

Tags: python, tkinter, tooltip, tk-toolkit, customtkinter

I'm using tkinter-tooltip and when I try to add a tooltip to a button consisting of only an image, it says `"NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'"`. It works if I do `text=" "` but I don't wanna make the text a space or anything, because its shape gets distorted. I just want to add a tooltip to image, is there any way to override this?

```
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image
from tktooltip import ToolTip

root = customtkinter.CTk()

icon = customtkinter.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open("icon.png"))
button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, width=10, height=10, text="", image=icon)
button.pack(pady=20, padx=20)

ToolTip(button, msg="A message", delay=0, follow=True,
        parent_kwargs={"bg": "black", "padx": 3, "pady": 3},
        fg="white", bg="orange", padx=7, pady=7)

root.mainloop()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python Projects\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    ToolTip(button, msg="A message", delay=0, follow=True,
  File "D:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tktooltip\tooltip.py", line 83, in __init__ 
    self.widget.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter, add="+")
  File "D:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 544, in bind
    self._text_label.bind(sequence, command, add=True)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'
```

Comment: have you tried to reverse the order of the ToolTip() and button.pack() calls?

Comment: Please, show the full traceback you get

Comment: This looks like a bug or poorly designed feature of CTkButton and/or CTkImage. The code works fine with a normal tkinter button.

Comment: @father_goose it's no use.

Comment: @buran I added as you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bryan said, it is a bug in `customtkinter` that when `text` option is an empty string, the internal label `self._text_label` will not be created and so it is `None`.  You can overcome this by setting `text=" "` instead.

Also it is better not to set `delay=0` in `ToolTip(...)` as it will make the tooltip not showing sometimes.  Just give `delay` a very small value like `0.01` for example.

```py
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image
from tktooltip import ToolTip

root = customtkinter.CTk()

icon = customtkinter.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open("icon.png"))
# set text=" "
button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, width=10, height=10, text=" ", image=icon)
button.pack(pady=20, padx=20)

# set delay=0.01
ToolTip(button, msg="A message", delay=0.01, follow=True,
        parent_kwargs={"bg": "black", "padx": 3, "pady": 3},
        fg="white", bg="orange", padx=7, pady=7)

root.mainloop()
```

Another option is to create a custom `CTkButton` class and override the `bind()` function:

```py
class MyButton(customtkinter.CTkButton):
    def bind(self, sequence=None, command=None, add=True):
        if not (add == "+" or add is True):
            raise ValueError("'add' argument can only be '+' or True to preserve internal callbacks")
        self._canvas.bind(sequence, command, add=True)
        if self._text_label:
            self._text_label.bind(sequence, command, add=True)
        if self._image_label:
            self._image_label.bind(sequence, command, add=True)
...
button = MyButton(master=root, width=20, height=20, text="", image=icon)
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll notify the dev about this. But as I stated in the post I don't wanna set text = " ", because the shape gets distorted.

Comment: Then you need to change the source of `ctk_button.py` of `customtkinter`. Or override the `bind()` by creating custom CTkButton class.